# Store PHP Page output in Memcached

Tags: php, memcached

I'm generating user profile using a PHP Script - post PHP processing its all HTML.

How can I direct this output into memcached?

I know how to save a PHP variable into memcached using set but how to I save a large snippet of HTML?

Do I somehow save this HTML to a variable and then set this into Memcached?

thanks

** Just trying to avoid having to generate the same page repetitively.

Comment: how PHP variable is different from a HTML snippet (string variable)? they are the same. So treat it in the same way.

Comment: They are not really the same... the variable thought was just an idea... Struggling to find out how to store HTML Fragments (Post PHP Processing) in Memcached... hummmmm

Comment: $memcache->set("post_processed_html", $html);
?
I believe the problem you have is how to get that post processed html? In this case, many (all?) popular frameworks can render the view and return the result as a variable rather than printing.